# Is it a good practice to use a one time loop to simulate goto in python?

Tags: python, loops, goto

`goto` is usually considered evil and are discouraged to be used. But sometimes `goto` gives a clearer and more readable organization of the code, for example: 
 I want to do some step by step computation, where the result of each step determines whether the following steps are needed, and if needed, which branch to go. The logic itself is a bit complicated, so there are couple of nested if statements. Assuming `goto` was available in python, a neat way to achieve this would be:

```
do_something 
if ...:
    goto zero
do_something
if case 1:
    do_something
    if ...:
        goto zero
    do_something
elif case 2:
    do_something
    if ...:
        goto zero
    do_something
....
result = compute_result(....)
goto next

zero:
result = 0

next:
do_something
```

Without the help of `goto`, it is possible to get the same behavior by introducing boolean variables to store flags and add additional `if` tests to turn on or off codes. But this way makes the control flow much less readable. One workaround would be to abuse a one time `for` loop to simulate the `goto` version of the above code, like below:

```
zero = True
for _ in range(1):
    do_something 
    if ...:
        break
    do_something
    if case 1:
        do_something
        if ...:
            break
        do_something
    elif case 2:
        do_something
        if ...:
            break
        do_something
    ....
    zero = False

if zero:
    result = 0
else
    result = compute_result(....)

do_something
```

My question is, is this the best approach to write a more readable code?

Comment: Use the function Luke: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: and `if case 1:` is invalid syntax anyway...

Comment: @Julien So is `...`. It's pseudo-code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
I think that, once you work through a Python tutorial, you will learn the proper control constructs such that *neither* of these outlines will look "good" to you.

Comment: Um, am I the only one that understands what he's asking?!

Comment: @StephenRauch The reason I don't want to put this inside a function is because it uses lots of local variables in the contex and making a function with lots of parameters looks ugly too.

Comment: I think you could use continue to accomplish this, since it appears you just want to continue in the loop.

Comment: @Prune I'm not a new python developer and I'm not asking basic question like how to use a control flow, and I don't need any tutorial to teach me this. What I'm asking is a more philosophical question:
We all say that goto is evil, but sometimes goto do simplify things and make the code cleaner. If this is the case, what is the best way to simulate goto?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm afraid so... I don't know whether it is because I didn't write my idea clearly, or because people didn't read and think carefully... I'm a python developer who has contributions to some famous open source python projects, and they ask me to read the tutorial....

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to break out of a calculation early is to use an exception:

```
class ExitCalculation(Exception): pass

try:
    do_something
    if time_to_goto_zero:
        raise ExitCalculation()
    do_something
    if ...:
        do_something
        if time_to_go_to_zero:
            raise ExitCalculation()
    result = compute_result()
except ExitCalculation:
    result = 0

do next thing
```

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions provide the same type of structured jumps without the implication of repeated execution:

```
class Foo(Exception):
    pass

try:
    do_something
    if ...:
        raise Foo
    do_something
    if case_1:
        do_something
        if ...:
            raise Foo
        do_something
    elif case_2:
        do_something
        if ...:
            raise Foo
        do_something
except Foo:
    result = 0
else:
    result = compute_result(...)
```

Which exception(s) you use are a matter of why your "gotos" break the regular control flow.

Comment: I know exception does the same thing, but is using exception to do control flow considered a bad practice?
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether or not using exceptions provide more readable code than heavily nested `if` statements.

Comment: Exception handling *is* a form of flow control; you just don't want to use it where there are clearer alternatives. Python itself uses two exception types (`StopIteration` and `SystemExit`) for flow control.

Comment: I sort of agree with you. And what do you think for-break vs try-raise-except, which is better? I think they are comparable, and both of them are sort of ugly compared with the goto version.

Comment: Well, I posted an exception-based answer rather than simply agreeing with your for-break proposal in a comment, so... :)

Comment: But seriously, a loop implies at least the possibility of multiple iterations, while a `try` block defines exactly what you want: a sequence of instructions that might be interrupted as various points.

Comment: In this case, the goto is used to bail from a calculation and take a default (at least, that's how I read it) and that is a well-accepted use for exceptions.